# Error after overriding create method in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm Overriding create method of serializer in order to manipulate validated_data and create object in a model, Although it works, in the end I get below error, i am not able to figure out why after lot of research.

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `shift_time` on serializer `PunchRawDataAndroidSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `PunchRawData` instance.
Original exception text was: 'PunchRawData' object has no attribute 'shift_time'.
```

```
class PunchRawDataAndroidSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee_id = serializers.CharField()
    shift_id = serializers.CharField()
    work_location_id = serializers.CharField()
    shift_time = serializers.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = PunchRawData
        fields = ['employee_id', 'shift_id','work_location_id', 'punch_type', 'actual_clock_datetime',
                  'emp_photo', 'created_at', 'updated_at','shift_time']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop('shift_time')
        request_data = self.context.get('request')
        user = request_data.user
        validated_data['user'] = user
        data = validated_data
        return PunchRawData.objects.create(**data)
```

```
class PunchRawDataAndroidViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    serializer_class = PunchRawDataAndroidSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FileUploadParser)
```

edit:

```
class PunchRawData(models.Model):
    PUNCH_TYPES = [("in", "Punch IN"), ("out", "Punch Out")]

    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name="punch_employee", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shift = models.ForeignKey(WorkShift, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_location = models.ForeignKey(HRMLocation, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                      null=True, related_name="punch_work_location")
    punch_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, choices=PUNCH_TYPES)
    user = models.ForeignKey("useraccounts.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    actual_clock_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    emp_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="selfies/%Y/%m/%d/%I/%M/%S/")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        strl = "{emp_id} [{shift_id}]".format(emp_id=self.employee.emp_id,
                                              shift_id=self.shift.shift_id)
        return strl

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Punch Raw Data"
        verbose_name_plural = "Punch Raw Data"
```

I get `shift_time` from frontend and it is not from model, hence i'm poping it out from validated_data in `create` method. is error related to `modelviewset`?

Comment: Can you show PunchRawData model class definition?

Comment: If your data is not that important try deleting migrations folder and than re-create migratons.

Answer (score 0):

Your model doesn't have the shift_time attribute. So if you try to save it, you will end with

> PunchRawData() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shift_time'

At the other hand you are getting AttributeError, because serializers.to_representation() tries to get a non-existing attribute when showing your freshly saved object.

If this should be a read-only attribute, you may do the following:

```
shift_time = serializers.TimeField(read_only=True)
```

and than remove the

```
validated_data.pop('shift_time')
```

from PunchRawDataAndroidSerializer.create(). You don't need this any more, because it is never submitted from your client.

If you need the opposite – your client should provide you that field, but you don't want it saved in your model, than the only thing, you should do, is:

```
shift_time = serializers.TimeField(write_only=True)
```

And if you need it to be bidirectional, than you should add it to your model.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Client is Posting, so we can't have the field has read_only.

Comment: OK, so there are the other two opportunities:
1. If you want the client to provide you with that field, but you don't want to save it in the database, than use write_only=True and that's it. Everything will work as expected.

If you need to write it to the database, than you need to add this field to your model too.

Comment: If this works for you, you should mark the answer as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Generic viewsets of django-rest-framework return the serialized representation of the model in response, so it's try to serialize the model including the `shift_time` key.

To avoid this problem you can specify the `shift_time` field as `write_only`. [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)

modify the `Meta` class on your model

```
class Meta:
    model = PunchRawData
    fields = ['employee_id', 'shift_id','work_location_id', 'punch_type', 'actual_clock_datetime',
              'emp_photo', 'created_at', 'updated_at','shift_time']
    extra_kwargs = {'shift_time': {'write_only': True}}
```

Comment: I tried this, it's not working. Your approach is right but i'm getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @wankata's answer we can override `__init__` method to have `write_only` field for only create method.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context['view'].action == 'create':
            self.fields['shift_time'].write_only = True
```